# Creating a kitchen sink Angular Material library template compile error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-library

Trying to create a library containing all the Angular Material modules for quick installation during prototyping.

Rather than copy and paste this module into the project, I'd like to just NPM install it:

```
// material.module.ts
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import { MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';

const mm = [
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatTreeModule,
  MatNativeDateModule
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ...mm ],
    exports: [...mm
    ],
    providers: [     
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {
    constructor(public matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
        // matIconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
    }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<MaterialModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: MaterialModule,
            providers: [MatIconRegistry]
        }
    }
}
```

So I created a new workspace `ng new workspace --create-application=false`.

And a module inside that workspace `ng g library material-module`.

And I removed everything except for the module pasted above.

The `package.json` file for the library looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "@fireflysemantics/material-module",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "*",
    "@angular/core": "*",
    "@angular/cdk": "*",
    "@angular/material": "*",
    "tslib": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

The peer dependencies are installed.

When I try to run the build it generates errors like this:

```
ERROR: @angular/forms/forms.ts(141,38): Error during template compile of 'NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'InjectionToken' was called.
@angular/forms/forms.ts(141,38): Error during template compile of 'NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'InjectionToken' was called.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `ng add @angular/material` inside the library project. Apparently this caused the issue.  I tried a brand new project with Angular Material added at the root level and that fixed it.